# Is there a page detailing how points are awarded?

Tags: support, reputation

I have a general understanding of how this works, but every now and then I just don't quite get it. I answered [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7288/was-e-t-a-jedi/48476#48476) question on SF&F SE and got 18 points but there is only 1 upvote. Is it because it's an old question? And I lost 2 points for changing the accepted answer on [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16404/where-was-director-tommy-wiseau-born-and-or-raised/16443#16443) question here on M&TV. Neither the Tour nor FAQ pages seem to break it down into explicit detail.

Is there a link detailing the reasons for awarding or rescinding Rep points? My search failed to give me a good page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked [your reputation log](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/16974/meat-trademark?tab=reputation) extensively enough? You get -2 when someone downvotes you, so that SF&F post got 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, resulting in +20-2 = +18 for you and 1 upvote for the answer.

The second case of getting -2 for changing the accepted answer is probably due to the fact that you get +2 for accepting an answer, but not if it's your own. But since you changed the accepted answer from *JohnSmithOptional*'s to yours, you lost the 2 that you once got for accepting his answer (marked as *"unaccept"* in [your reputation log](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/6492/meat-trademark?tab=reputation)).

In general the reputation scores are explained [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) (though, I don't see a rule for not getting +2 if the accepted answer is yours right away). Wait, [I found it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/):

> Now, there are some special rules around owner-accepted answers, to
>   prevent gaming:
>
> - Wait 48 hours. You must wait 2 days from the time you originally asked your question before you can accept your own answer. This gives
>     other users a chance to answer the question in good faith, and earn
>     the accepted answer.
> - No change in sort order. Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they
>     stay in standard sort order like any other answer.
> - No reputation is earned. Normally, accepted answers confer +15 rep to the answerer and +2 to the owner. **Owner accepted answers do not
>     earn rep (or badges) for anyone.**

Comment: That probably explains it. I figured out the unaccepted answer part *and was editing my question to reflect that* when I saw an answer. As to the first part, the log doesn't seem to tell me I was upvoted 2 and downvoted once. Thanks for unbending my mind.

Comment: @MeatTrademark It does, just expand the arrow next to *"Was E.T. a Jedi?"*. I just did that to check it. It says *"+10 upvote, -2 downvote, +10 upvote"*.

Comment: Thanks. To quote Barton Fink, "Is the egg showing or what?" I didn't click the arrow, not realizing it was a drop-down. Thanks a million. Or at least +1 and acceptance.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Haha, too bad meta doesn't give reputation at all, but thanks anyway. ;-)

Comment: And now my question seems like it was asked by an idiot. :( Everything's obvious and pedantic when you know the answer...

Comment: @MeatTrademark - don't worry about it

Comment: I can only hope you are quoting **The Room**. I definitely have breast cancer. :)